# Change the value of a custom data attribute

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have a tooltip for a phone number field that on hover is displaying its value as xxx-xxx-xxxx as a format example for the field, my client wants the xxx-xxx-xxxx replaced with numbers instead of x's and I'm trying to use jquery to change the value but I haven't had any luck.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="form-type-textfield form-item-customer-profile-billing-field-cbi-phone-und-0-value form-item form-group" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="xxx-xxx-xxxx">
```

And here are a couple of code examples that I've tried but can't get to work

```
$('.form-item-customer-profile-billing-field-cbi-phone-und-0-value').data('original-title', '412-555-1212');
```

and

```
$('.form-item-customer-profile-billing-field-cbi-phone-und-0-value').attr('data-original-title', '412-555-1212');
```

Comment: So long selector. Wow!

Comment: @Satpal and it's only a class!

Comment: First time i see so looooong class:D Did you try to add an id?

Comment: An id wouldn't change anything @Alek

Comment: This is working exactly as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/d4b2a/ - what problem are you having?

Comment: How are you accessing the value from the data attribute?

Comment: I think I may know how to fix this. There are two points we need to remember:

Comment: I think I may know how to fix this. There are two points we need to remember: (1) There's the HTML5 data attribute and then there's jQuery's internal cache; you can change one without affecting the other. It matters whether you're using .data() or .attr() for the tooltip. (2) Do you initialize the tooltip after changing or before? If you are using .attr() you have to make the change before you initialize the tooltip as the tooltip may be constructed at runtime. [This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/xY7jA/1/) should put to rest any doubts. :) Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Your second try does work:

http://jsfiddle.net/r6826/

```
$('.form-item-customer-profile-billing-field-cbi-phone-und-0-value').attr('data-original-title', '412-555-1212');
```

Inspect the element and you will see it changed the attribute:

[image]

Edit: And I do agree with the comments to your question: Those are nasty class names :)

Comment: So it is. I'm not sure why it won't work in the site then. Thanks for the prompt responses.